# rule for Normality skewness $<|2.0|$ , kurtosis $<|9.0|$?

Tags: distributions, references, normality-assumption, skewness, kurtosis

Quoting:

> > As can be seen in Table 1, the experimental and control group distribution were sufficiently normal for the purpose of conducting a $t$-test (skewness $<|2.0|$ , kurtosis $<|9.0|$ ; Schmider, Ziegler, Danay, Beyer, & Bühner, 2010).

I checked the article that is cited. Nothing in the article refers explicitly to this rule for Normality skewness $<|2.0|$ , kurtosis $<|9.0|$.

Anybody has an article backing this up?

Comment: What does the Schmider, Ziegler, Danay, Beyer, & Bühner (2010) paper say? Notice that they use word "sufficiently", so they may not be suggesting that the statistics prove anything, but may just be using them to illustrate that it is "close enough".